# Can Firebase functions written with nodejs sdk pass through firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

We are currently writing CRUD rest api operations with firebase functions using firbase’s node-js sdk.

When writing to firestore db, will the firestore db rules still apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security rules *only* apply to code on web and mobile clients using the Firebase SDKs.  (And also the REST API when provided with a Firebase Authentication user token.)

Security rules *never* apply to code on backends using the server SDKs, including the Firebase Admin SDK, which wraps the Cloud Firestore SDK for various languages.  The rules are completely skipped.  This includes the node SDK, as they are intended to be used on backends such as Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks Doug for confirming. Any popular express middleware to validate the requests?